# Java command-line problems with .jar libraries

Tags: java, command-line, jar, compilation

I have a single .java (driver.java) file I'm trying to compile and run from the command-line. It uses the external library called `EXT.jar`, whose structure is just a folder called EXT with a few dozen classes within it.

So I run:

```
javac -cp EXT.jar driver.java
```

This compiles the class just fine.

then when I run:

```
java -cp EXT.jar driver
```

I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Oddly enough, if I unpack the JAR (so now I have a folder in the root directory called EXT), the last command works just fine!! Driver will execute!

Is there any way I can make the driver.class look for the need class files from `EXT.jar/EXT/*class` instead of an actual EXT folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're compiling the class to the local directory. So when you run it, you need to include the current directory in your classpath. E.g.:

```
java -cp .;EXT.jar driver
```

Or in linux:

```
java -cp .:EXT.jar driver
```

With the way you have it now, you're saying your classpath is *only* EXT.jar (along with whatever is in the CLASSPATH environment variable) and nothing else (which is why the current directory, where driver.class is located, is excluded)

Comment: Will do. I apparently need to wait 15 minutes to accept an answer :)

Comment: Thanx Matt, your answer did work for me in case of a single jar, but now I need 2 use another jar. Both jars are in a folder called "libs" in my project. But couldn't get it working. I am using Ubuntu. plz help

Comment: @AndroidGuy you can just continue to list the JARs, separated by colon. E.g. `java -cp .:libs/one.jar:libs/two.jar MainClass`

Comment: Just a note for my own personal reference, but you always have to specify the _classpath_ first, **BEFORE** the executable bytecode (Java class) name! For example, the following didn't work for me (begin hair pulling): `java MyApp -cp .;EXT.jar`                                     
While this worked just fine: 

`java -cp .;EXT.jar MyApp`

Comment: I'm sure @AndroidGuy has figured it out by now, but for anyone else coming along `java -cp .:libs/* MainClass` covers the n JARs case